# Add a checkboxes to existing Treeview in WPF

Tags: wpf, checkbox, treeview

I have an existing treeview in WPF in which I would like to add checkboxes

Here the code

I have a class Person which contains all the structure

Person.cs

```
public class Person
    {
        readonly List<Person> _children = new List<Person>();
        public IList<Person> Children
        {
            get { return _children; }
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

As I read in some other posts, I use ViewModel

PersonViewModel.cs

```
public class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Data
        readonly ReadOnlyCollection<PersonViewModel> _children;
        readonly PersonViewModel _parent;
        readonly Person _person;

        bool _isExpanded=true;
        bool _isSelected;
        #endregion Data

        #region Constructors
        public PersonViewModel(Person person): this(person, null)
        {
        }

        private PersonViewModel(Person person, PersonViewModel parent)
        {
            _person = person;
            _parent = parent;

            _children = new ReadOnlyCollection<PersonViewModel>(
                    (from child in _person.Children
                     select new PersonViewModel(child, this))
                     .ToList<PersonViewModel>());
        }
        #endregion Constructors

        #region Person Properties
        public ReadOnlyCollection<PersonViewModel> Children
        {
            get { return _children; }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _person.Name; }
        }

        #endregion Person Properties

        #region Presentation Members
        #region IsExpanded

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets/sets whether the TreeViewItem 
        /// associated with this object is expanded.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsExpanded
        {
            get { return _isExpanded; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _isExpanded)
                {
                    _isExpanded = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
                }

                // Expand all the way up to the root.
                if (_isExpanded && _parent != null)
                    _parent.IsExpanded = true;
            }
        }

        #endregion IsExpanded

        #region IsSelected

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets/sets whether the TreeViewItem 
        /// associated with this object is selected.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _isSelected)
                {
                    _isSelected = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion IsSelected

        #region NameContainsText

        public bool NameContainsText(string text)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Name))
                return false;

            return Name.IndexOf(text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1;
        }

        #endregion NameContainsText

        #region Parent

        public PersonViewModel Parent
        {
            get { return _parent; }
        }

        #endregion Parent

        #endregion Presentation Members        

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    }
```

The family tree ViewModel

FamilyTreeViewModel.cs

public class FamilyTreeViewModel
{

```
#region Data
readonly PersonViewModel _rootPerson;
#endregion Data

#region Constructor
public FamilyTreeViewModel(Person rootPerson)
{
    _rootPerson = new PersonViewModel(rootPerson);

    FirstGeneration = new ReadOnlyCollection<PersonViewModel>(
        new PersonViewModel[]
        {
            _rootPerson
        });
}
#endregion Constructor

#region Properties
#region FirstGeneration
/// <summary>
/// Returns a read-only collection containing the first person 
/// in the family tree, to which the TreeView can bind.
/// </summary>
public ReadOnlyCollection<PersonViewModel> FirstGeneration { get; }
#endregion FirstGeneration
#endregion Properties
```

}

The xaml code
MainWindow.xaml

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding FirstGeneration}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />

        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        readonly FamilyTreeViewModel _familyTree;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Person rootPerson = new Person
            {
                Name="Application Architect Right",
                Children =
                {
                    new Person
                    {
                        Name="Generate"
                    },
                    new Person
                    {
                        Name="Instances rights",
                        Children =
                        {
                            new Person
                            {
                                Name = "Create"
                            },
                            new Person
                            {
                                Name = "Modify"
                            },
                            new Person
                            {
                                Name = "Delete"
                            },
                            new Person
                            {
                                Name = "Exceptions Management"
                            }
                        }

                    },
                    new Person
                    {
                        Name="Templates rights",
                        Children =
                        {
                            new Person
                            {
                                Name = "Create"
                            },
                            new Person
                            {
                                Name = "Modify"
                            },
                            new Person
                            {
                                Name = "Delete"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Person
                    {
                        Name="Parameters rights",
                        Children =
                        {
                            new Person
                            {
                                Name = "Create"
                            },
                            new Person
                            {
                                Name = "Modify"
                            },
                            new Person
                            {
                                Name = "Delete"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                }
            };


            // Create UI-friendly wrappers around the 
            // raw data objects (i.e. the view-model).
            _familyTree = new FamilyTreeViewModel(rootPerson);


            // Let the UI bind to the view-model.
            DataContext = _familyTree;

        }
    }
```

Can someone can help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but have you tried editing your XAML like this?

```
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
      <StackPanel Orientation=Horizontal>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <Checkbox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected} />
      </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Since there is no checkbox by default in a treeview in wpf, editing the template of the items to add a checkbox is the way to go.

Since the checkbox is binded to the IsSelected property of your PersonViewModel, you could do something like this if you want to update the selection of the childs

```
public bool IsSelected
{
   ...
    set
    {
        if (value != _isSelected)
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            this.UpdateChildSelection();
        }
    }
}


private void UpdateChildSelection()
{
    foreach(var child in Children)
    {
        child.IsSelected = this.IsSelected;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This effectively allows me to add checkboxes. 
Now at the code level, how do we manage the selection.
Select a parent, check all children.
Checking only one child puts the parent in indeterminate.

Comment: Modified my answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is my base ViewModel class for TreeView items, which includes cascading checking.

```
public class perTreeViewItemViewModelBase : perViewModelBase
{
    // a dummy item used in lazy loading mode, ensuring that each node has at least one child so that the expand button is shown
    private static perTreeViewItemViewModelBase LoadingDataItem { get; }

    static perTreeViewItemViewModelBase()
    {
        LoadingDataItem = new perTreeViewItemViewModelBase { Caption = "Loading Data ..." };
    }

    private readonly perObservableCollection<perTreeViewItemViewModelBase> _childrenList = new perObservableCollection<perTreeViewItemViewModelBase>();

    public perTreeViewItemViewModelBase(bool addLoadingDataItem = false)
    {
        if (addLoadingDataItem)
            _childrenList.Add(LoadingDataItem);
    }

    private string _caption;

    public string Caption
    {
        get { return _caption; }
        set { Set(nameof(Caption), ref _caption, value); }
    }

    public void ClearChildren()
    {
        _childrenList.Clear();
    }

    public void AddChild(perTreeViewItemViewModelBase child)
    {
        if (_childrenList.Any() && _childrenList.First() == LoadingDataItem)
            ClearChildren();

        _childrenList.Add(child);
        SetChildPropertiesFromParent(child);
    }

    protected void SetChildPropertiesFromParent(perTreeViewItemViewModelBase child)
    {
        child.Parent = this;

        if (IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault())
            child.IsChecked = true;
    }

    public void AddChildren(IEnumerable<perTreeViewItemViewModelBase> children)
    {
        foreach (var child in children)
            AddChild(child);
    }

    protected perTreeViewItemViewModelBase Parent { get; private set; }

    private bool? _isChecked = false;

    public bool? IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            if (Set(nameof(IsChecked), ref _isChecked, value))
            {
                foreach (var child in Children)
                    if (child.IsEnabled)
                        child.SetIsCheckedIncludingChildren(value);

                SetParentIsChecked();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _isExpanded;

    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return _isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            if (!Set(nameof(IsExpanded), ref _isExpanded, value) || IsInitialised || IsInitialising)
                return;

            var unused = InitialiseAsync();
        }
    }

    private bool _isEnabled = true;

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set { Set(nameof(IsEnabled), ref _isEnabled, value); }
    }

    public bool IsInitialising { get; private set; }
    public bool IsInitialised { get; private set; }

    public async Task InitialiseAsync()
    {
        if (IsInitialised || IsInitialising)
            return;

        IsInitialising = true;
        await InitialiseChildrenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        foreach (var child in InitialisedChildren)
            SetChildPropertiesFromParent(child);
        IsInitialised = true;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Children));
    }

    protected virtual Task InitialiseChildrenAsync()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public IEnumerable<perTreeViewItemViewModelBase> Children => IsInitialised
        ? InitialisedChildren
        : _childrenList;

    // override this as required in descendent classes
    // e.g. if Children is a union of multiple child item collections which are populated in InitialiseChildrenAsync()
    protected virtual IEnumerable<perTreeViewItemViewModelBase> InitialisedChildren => _childrenList;

    private bool _isSelected;

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            // ensure that all ancestor items are expanded, so this item will be visible
            if (value)
            {
                var parent = Parent;
                while (parent != null)
                {
                    parent.IsExpanded = true;
                    parent = parent.Parent;
                }
            }

            if (_isSelected == value)
                return;

            // use DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle so that we wait for any children of newly expanded items to be fully created in the
            // parent TreeView, before setting IsSelected for this item (which will scroll it into view - see perTreeViewItemHelper)
            perDispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() => Set(nameof(IsSelected), ref _isSelected, value), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);

            // note that by rule, a TreeView can only have one selected item, but this is handled automatically by 
            // the control - we aren't required to manually unselect the previously selected item.
        }
    }

    private void SetIsCheckedIncludingChildren(bool? value)
    {
        _isChecked = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsChecked));

        foreach (var child in Children)
            if (child.IsEnabled)
                child.SetIsCheckedIncludingChildren(value);
    }

    private void SetIsCheckedThisItemOnly(bool? value)
    {
        _isChecked = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsChecked));
    }

    private void SetParentIsChecked()
    {
        var parent = Parent;

        while (parent != null)
        {
            var hasIndeterminateChild = parent.Children.Any(c => c.IsEnabled && !c.IsChecked.HasValue);

            if (hasIndeterminateChild)
                parent.SetIsCheckedThisItemOnly(null);
            else
            {
                var hasSelectedChild = parent.Children.Any(c => c.IsEnabled && c.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault());
                var hasUnselectedChild = parent.Children.Any(c => c.IsEnabled && !c.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault());

                if (hasUnselectedChild && hasSelectedChild)
                    parent.SetIsCheckedThisItemOnly(null);
                else
                    parent.SetIsCheckedThisItemOnly(hasSelectedChild);
            }

            parent = parent.Parent;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Caption;
    }
}
```

For more details and an example of its usage, see my recent [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-behaviors-part-2-treeview/).